# Cannot extract an amount from string with vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I have the following

"PRICE
    40,06€  "

which contains as I can from notepad++ spaces and tab characters I used something like the following to get the number but nothing happens.. I want to get the amount 40,06€

```
Function ExtractAmount(data As String) As Variant
  Dim s As String
  s = Split(data, "PRICE")(5) 
  ExtractAmount = CCur(Val(s))
End Function
```

And I call it

```
Set price = ie.Document.querySelector(".price")
wks.Cells(i, "E").Value = ExtractAmount(price.innerText)
```

How can I do it? thank you

** The following url

https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=101&search=wd10ezex

or such has this moment as a result for price the phrase "Discount 40,50€ from 50€" which does not gets the amount with one selector

Comment: Did you Google for VBA Split function?

Comment: try   `s = Split(data, "PRICE")(1)`

Comment: I did it with (1) but does not work I put 5 to exclude the first 5 or I got it wrong?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant html? Is there an URL we can use?

Comment: Even if its on Greek https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=10858 the PRICE is TIMH :)

Comment: then did you solve it?

Comment: I get nothing neither the amount or text

Comment: **s = Split(data, "PRICE")(5)**
Please consider not to hard-code numerical values. What if 40,06€ turns into 40, 06€ or similar? Generally you should build your code on a more rubust structure than the one you're employing now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different class selector

```
text = IE.document.querySelector(".price-val").innerText
```

VBA:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, text As String
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate2 "https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=10858"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        text = IE.document.querySelector(".price-val").innerText
        Debug.Print Trim$(text)
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

You can use Or css selector syntax if testing for presence of different class e.g. the new price

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, text As String
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=101&search=wd10ezex"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        text = IE.document.querySelector(".price-val, .price-new").innerText
        Debug.Print Trim(Trim$(text))
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried it but there are some products that they write "Discount 35,60€ from 40,50€" . if I put this selector then I get an exit sub because price is Nothing

Comment: It is working only if cell does not contain the "Discount 35,60€ from 40,50€" as a phrase

Comment: https://www.overshop.gr/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=101&search=wd10ezex

Comment: So if there are 3 or 4 cases with different selectors I should included them all correct?

Comment: What do you mean editing the urls? to put them in my question you mean?